# Wrapping up the repetitive sql statements into transaction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transaction

I have a task to cancel more than 90 contracts, and I would like to know if it's possible to do it in one shot, rather than running manually all of them. I have 3 statements which I need to run per each contract. These are the examples below.

When I run the first statement:

```
UPDATE `dbo2`.`allcontracts` SET `ctr_status`='4' WHERE `ctr_id`='4483';
```

I'm changing the status of contract with id =  **4483**. Status will be 4 for all contracts ( more than 90 of them ).

When I run the second statement:

```
INSERT INTO `dbo2`.`tctrchanges`
      (`chg_ctr_id`, `chg_type`, `chg_date`, `chg_status`,
       `chg_appr_date`, `chg_emp_id`, `chg_req`, `chg_reserved`)
    VALUES
      ('4483', '0', '2017-06-02 11:11:11', '1',
       '2017-06-02 11:11:11', '3', '31', '4483');
```

I need to insert contract id from the first statement into `chg_ctr_id` and `chg_reserved`. I will also need id of column `chg_id` which is PK AI from this second statement above, to automatically assign it to third statement below in column `note_text` as URL parameter. ( For example below chg_id=**5334** )

```
 INSERT INTO `dbo2`.`allnotes`
       (`note_dt`, `note_user`, `note_ref_id`, `note_type`,
        `note_text`,
        `note_emp_id`, `note_reserved`)
     VALUES
       ('2017-06-02 11:11:11', 'mikeb', '328515', '2',
        '<b>Automatic Note:</b> <a href=\"ctrchange4.asp?chg_id=5334\">Contract was Cancelled</a> ',
        '31', '4483');
```

As you can notice, the column `note_reserved` will have the same contract id from the first statement, and column `note_emp_id` will have the same static value as column`chg_req` from the second statement.

All other values can be the same for all contracts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `chg_req`/`note_emp_id` the same for all contracts? if not, where does the value come from?

Comment: Yes!! They are the same for all contracts. Static number 31

Comment: In `tctrchanges`, using the `contract_id`/`chg_ctr_id` values you provide, and the known hard-coded values from your script, but not using `chg_id`, can you uniquely identify a row? That is to say, I assume there could be multiple rows per `chg_ctr_id` (if not, things become trivial), but would there be only one row per `chg_ctr_id` and `chg_date` (for example)?

Comment: Yes, it would be only one row. Date can be the current date it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `DelContracts_20170607` (`contract_id` varchar(32), `chg_id` varchar(32));
INSERT INTO `DelContracts_20160607` VALUES ('1234', NULL);
-- ... insert rest of contract IDs

SET @DelDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y-%m-%d %T');

UPDATE `dbo2`.`allcontracts` ac JOIN `DelContracts_20170607` d ON (ac.`ctr_id` = d.`contract_id`)
   SET ac.`ctr_status`='4'
;

INSERT INTO `dbo2`.`tctrchanges`
  (`chg_ctr_id`, `chg_type`, `chg_date`, `chg_status`, `chg_appr_date`,
   `chg_emp_id`, `chg_req`, `chg_reserved`)
  SELECT `contract_id`, '0', @DelDate, '1', @DelDate, '3', '31', `contract_id`
    FROM `DelContracts_20170607`
;

UPDATE `DelContracts_20170607` d JOIN `dbo2`.`tctrchanges` tcc ON (d.`contract_id` = tcc`chg_reserved`)
   SET d.`chg_id` = CAST(tcc.`chg_id` as char(32))
 WHERE tcc.`chg_date` = @DelDate
;

INSERT INTO `dbo2`.`allnotes`
  (`note_dt`, `note_user`, `note_ref_id`, `note_type`, `note_text`, `note_emp_id`, `note_reserved`)
  SELECT @DelDate, 'mikeb', '328515', '2',
         CONCAT('<b>Automatic Note:</b> <a href=\"ctrchange4.asp?chg_id=',`chg_id`,'">Contract was Cancelled</a> '),
         '31', `contract_id`
    FROM `DelContracts_20170607`
;

DROP TABLE `DelContracts_20170607`;
```

NOTE: Code is untested.

First, you create a table to hold the contract ID values. Set this up to also hold the `chg_id` values form `tctrchanges`, once they're created.

Insert all the contract IDs into the table.

Next set a variable to the current date and time.

Update `allcontracts` by `JOIN`ing it to your newly created table.

Insert your rows into `tctrchanges` by selecting `contract_id`, the date variable, and the hardcoded values from your table.

Next, update your table, setting the `chg_id` value for each `contract_id`. You find the `chg_id` based on each row's `contract_id` and the value from your date variable. This is why we put the date in the variable instead of directly calling `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`; so we'd be sure we had the matching date when we went to search.

Then, insert into `allnotes` by selecting the hard-coded values (concatenating the `chg_id` into the URL) and the `contract_id` from your table yet again.

Finally, delete the table you created.

Comment: And use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: @RickJames -  I looked at that (I was originally thinking this would probably have to be done via a script to generate the actual commands, in which you'd do each contract individually). When the OP said `chg_cttr_id` and `chg_date` should uniquely identify a record in `tctrchanges`, I saw this could be done at the set level.

Comment: Updated to clarify - all the contract IDs are added to the table you create; the following statements then deal with the entire lot at once, rather than one at a time.

Comment: It works like a charm with small typos, and I had a problem with CASTING, I don't know if it's a bag. This part: **CAST(tcc.`chg_id` as varchar(32))** I needed to change to char, instead of varchar. Very interesting approach. I thought that you'll use last insert id as Rick James mentioned. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No worries. Just a small typo with a capital letter in the table name: Line 2 `DelCOntracts_20160607`, and line with CAST where needs to be char instead of varchar(32). I can't edit your code, because it needs to be at least 6 characters to be able to edit :-) Cheers!